# AWS S3: Is it possible to grant access to all buckets except one, without using a deny

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'd like to create an AWS policy to grant access to all buckets except one, but I do NOT want to use a deny. Reason being I want to also write policies to grant access to specific objects within the bucket and a deny blocks that.

I've tried this but it does not work (it's an improper use of `aws:SourceArn`), but it gives you an idea of what I'd like to achieve.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": [
                        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
                        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to be like?:

```
  "Condition": {
      "StringNotLike": {
          "s3:prefix": [
              "somename/",
              "someothername/"
          ]
      }
  }
```

Comment: This would almost work for me, but I would have to apply it as a bucket policy which has a max size of 20kb, but is not quite acceptable for my situation.